# Fos userBundle logout issue

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

**Following are my security.yml settings**

form_login:

```
         check_path: /%cluburlidentifier%/backend/login_check
         login_path: /%cluburlidentifier%/backend/signin
```

logout:

```
       path:   /%cluburlidentifier%/backend/signout
       target: /%cluburlidentifier%/backend/signin
```

I signin using **/myclub/backend/signin**. Permission of the user is Superadmin. When i tried to logout using different path, like, **/myhome/backend/signout**, it shows error "**You must activate the logout in your security firewall configuration.**".

**%cluburlidentifier% is a dynamic parameter taken from url.**

**How can I change the logout path defined in the security.yml after login..? Is there any session or something like to set...??**

Please help me !!

---

**The following is my full security.yml firewall config**

```
firewalls:
    frontend:
      pattern:    /%cluburlidentifier%/backend/.*
      provider:   fos_userbundle
      anonymous: ~          
      form_login:
          check_path: /%cluburlidentifier%/backend/login_check
          login_path: /%cluburlidentifier%/backend/signin
          username_parameter: _username
          password_parameter: _password
          csrf_parameter: _csrf_token
          intention: authenticate               
          post_only: true
          remember_me: true
          #use_referer: true
          always_use_default_target_path: true
          default_target_path: contact_index
      logout:
          path:   /%cluburlidentifier%/backend/signout
          target: /%cluburlidentifier%/backend/signin
          invalidate_session: true
          delete_cookies:
              a: { path: null, domain: null }
              b: { path: null, domain: null }
      remember_me:
          key:      "123456"
          lifetime: 31536000 # 365 days in seconds
          path:     fos_user_security_login
          domain:   ~ # Defaults to the current domain from $_SERVER
          always_remember_me: true
```

In that, first im trying to login with url like "**localhost:8080/twilight/backend/signin**", where twilight is the cluburl identifier. Afet login he redirects to "**localhost:8080/twilight/backend/contact**"

The logged user have the superadmin previlage. So he can moved to the next club by changing the cluburl identifier without triggering one more login. That means, just changing the url to "**localhost:8080/myclub/backend/contact**" in the browser..

**That also works...But the problem is, when he tried to logout using the url "**localhost:8080/myclub/backend/logout**" after login with "**localhost:8080/twilight/backend/signin**", couldn't work... 
I know it is a negative requirement...But is it possible...??**

Also i didn't get the logged user details if i changed the url path...Is there any way to that also?

Plz help me....

Comment: Can you replace the extract with your full `security.yml`? What do you mean by 'change the logout path **AFTER** login? What version of symfony are you running? Have you tried replacing all the urls with `routenames` instead of using absolute urls?